# Filter R dataframe to n most frequent cases and order by frequency

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

In a dataframe with repeat values, I want the rows for the most frequent `n` cases, say the two most frequently occurring. The code below does this, selecting rows where `x==3` or `x==4` and return the rows in that order.

I don't want to have to use the value 5; however, I want some way of programmatically stating the top 2 most frequent x values, without knowing a threshold (5 in this example) apriori. In addition, I would like to order the resulting dataframe by frequency of occurrence, so `x==4` rows come before `x==3` rows.

I am presuming it is related to `count`, `top_n` or `slice_max` and `arrange` but maybe not!

Any hints on how to do this with `dplyr` would be greatly appreciated.

```
require(tidyverse)
adf <- data.frame(x=c(rep(2,5),rep(3,7), rep(4,9), 1), y=1:22)
adf %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(n() > 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another `tidyverse` option, where I use `add_count` to get the number of observations per group, then I `filter` the 2 groups with the highest number of observations. Then, I `arrange` by the frequency of occurence.

```
library(tidyverse)

adf %>%
  add_count(x) %>% 
  filter(n %in% tail(sort(unique(n)),2)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n))
```

**Output**

```
   x  y n
1  4 13 9
2  4 14 9
3  4 15 9
4  4 16 9
5  4 17 9
6  4 18 9
7  4 19 9
8  4 20 9
9  4 21 9
10 3  6 7
11 3  7 7
12 3  8 7
13 3  9 7
14 3 10 7
15 3 11 7
16 3 12 7
```

**Data**

```
adf <- structure(list(x = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1), y = 1:22), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by calculating the size of each group using `n()` and then filtering on that. If you want them in order, can also use `dplyr::arrange()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

adf %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(size = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(size >= sort(unique(size), TRUE)[2]) %>%
  arrange(desc(size))
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>        x     y  size
#>    <dbl> <int> <int>
#>  1     4    13     9
#>  2     4    14     9
#>  3     4    15     9
#>  4     4    16     9
#>  5     4    17     9
#>  6     4    18     9
#>  7     4    19     9
#>  8     4    20     9
#>  9     4    21     9
#> 10     3     6     7
#> 11     3     7     7
#> 12     3     8     7
#> 13     3     9     7
#> 14     3    10     7
#> 15     3    11     7
#> 16     3    12     7
```

Comment: is this something you could also do with slice?